# Why is E-P-I-C unable to detect PadWalker?

Tags: eclipse, perl, debugging, epic

I have Eclipse (3.5-32) on my Unix machine. I have installed [E-P-I-C](http://e-p-i-c.sf.net/) updates for the stable 0.5.x and [`PadWalker`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PadWalker) (1.5).

Since I am a local user with no `sudo` rights I have installed `PadWalker` in a different folder. I have set this path as the environment variable `PERL5LIB`.

When I do `echo $PERL5LIB`  or  `perl -le 'print foreach @INC'`, I can see the `PadWalker` module installed.

But when I try to debug using Eclipse, it says "Error: Install PadWalker".

For the time being, to get this working I have explicitly added this PadWalker to my project using the Properties option in Eclipse.

Is there a better way to do it so that I don't have to add Padwalker to my project every time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first guess is that you didn't set PERL5LIB in the process that spawns Eclipse, but in some other process. If so, what you see at the prompt using `perl -le 'print foreach @INC'` wouldn't reflect what EPIC's perl sees.

I use a locally installed version of Perl, so I don't need special permissions or PERL5LIB. You can use [`perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App%3a%3aperlbrew) to do this. Then just tell EPIC to use a build of Perl you installed using `perlbrew` and for which you installed PadWalker.

Comment: I have set the PERL5LIB path correctly according to me as I see all the libraries included in it.

Comment: I checked the PERL5LIB path and it seems correct to me,as I can see other libraries working fine. I checked PerlBrew, it says it keeps a seperate environment of perl in local directory. I dont want that. I am a Perl newbie so I may have understood things incorreclty.If so please guide me over this.

Comment: @Amit, What happens when you place `use PadWalker;` in a source file. Does the syntax checker find it? If not, what's the error message. Specifically. Also, does it give an error for `use PadWalkerX;`?

Comment: u were correct... the problem was PERL5LIB ... m sorry.. The issue was that while extending PERL5LIB i added only the lib folder while I had to add site_perl too. After adding the /custom_util/lib and /custom_util/lib/site_perl to PERL5LIB..it works now.... Thanks a ton !!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error while upgrading my system to version (2020-12) of Eclipse on Linux Mint 20. I discovered that the problem was that the loader required version 2.3 of PadWalker rather than the latest version (2.5). Simply downgrading PadWalker with "sudo cpanm PadWalker@2.3" resolved the problem.

For reference: putting "use PadWalker" in a program and attempting to debug it provided an error description which gave the required version of PadWalker.